# how to set sprite as backgroound in AndEngine?

Tags: android, background, andengine, sprite

I am new in AndEngine. I want to set an image as background in my game.I am able to do this job but problem is that when i set a sprite as background then all other sprites in current seen become hidden. Here is the code :

```
public class SplashScene extends Scene {
BaseActivity activity;
Sprite sprite1,sprite2,backgrondSprite;

public SplashScene() {
    activity = BaseActivity.getSharedInstance();

    backgrondSprite = new Sprite(0, 0,
            BaseActivity.getSharedInstance().mBackgroundTextureRegion,
            BaseActivity.getSharedInstance().getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    setBackground(new SpriteBackground(backgrondSprite));


     sprite1 = new Sprite(32, 32,
            BaseActivity.getSharedInstance().mBirdTextureRegion, 
            BaseActivity.getSharedInstance().getVertexBufferObjectManager());

     sprite2 = new Sprite(32, 32,
                BaseActivity.getSharedInstance().mBirdTextureRegion, 
                BaseActivity.getSharedInstance().getVertexBufferObjectManager());

     sprite1.setPosition(-sprite1.getWidth(), activity.mCamera.getHeight() / 2);
     sprite2.setPosition(activity.mCamera.getWidth(),
            activity.mCamera.getHeight() / 2);

    attachChild(sprite1);
    attachChild(sprite2);
    attachChild(backgrondSprite);

    sprite1.registerEntityModifier(new MoveXModifier(1, sprite1.getX(),
            activity.mCamera.getWidth() / 2 - sprite1.getWidth()));
    sprite2.registerEntityModifier(new MoveXModifier(1, sprite2.getX(),
            activity.mCamera.getWidth() / 2));

    loadResources();
}

void loadResources() {
    DelayModifier dMod = new DelayModifier(2,
            new IEntityModifierListener() {

                @Override
                public void onModifierStarted(IModifier<IEntity> arg0,
                        IEntity arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onModifierFinished(IModifier<IEntity> arg0,
                        IEntity arg1) {
                    activity.setCurrentScene(new MainMenuScene());
                }
            });

    registerEntityModifier(dMod);
}
```

}
How can i make sprite1 and sprite2 still displayed with another sprite as background ???
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried attaching your sprites AFTER attaching the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.. That's right; ".. attaching your sprites AFTER attaching the background"

and you should know zIndex..

This code working too..

```
attachChild(sprite1);
attachChild(sprite2);
attachChild(background);

sprite1.setZIndex(1);
sprite2.setZIndex(1);
background.setZIndex(0);

scene.sortChildren();
```

background's index is 0 then when sorted, it settles to the bottom..

(it's sometimes necessary when playing)